# Suppose that $X$ is a random variable with $E(X^{n})=3^{n}(n+1)!$ for $n \geq 1$. Find the distribution of $X$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions

I tried using the moment generating function. I got:
$M_{X}(t)=E(e^{tX})=\Sigma_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)(3t)^{n}$. But I don't understand which distribution would it be.

Comment: Hint:

1) Apply [derivative of geometric sequence](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Derivative_of_Geometric_Sequence)

2) Use the mgf of [Gamma distribution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've found

$$M_X(t) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} (n+1)(3t)^n$$

We observe that this is almost the same power series as

$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^2} = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty (n+1)x^n$$

Thus $$M_X(t) = \frac{1}{(1-3t)^2}$$

I'll assume that the probability density function $f_X(x)$ we are looking for is defined to be $0$ for negative values of $x$.

If we expand the definition of the moment-generating function

$$\begin{align}
M_X(t) = E(e^{tX}) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{tx}f_X(x)dx &= \int_{-\infty}^0e^{tx} \cdot 0dx + \int_0^\infty e^{tx}f_X(x)dx \\
&= \int_0^\infty e^{tx}f_X(x)dx
\end{align}$$

We can observe that $M_X(t) = \mathcal{L}\{f_X(x)\}(-t)$, where $\mathcal{L}\{f_X(x)\}(-t)$ is the one-sided Laplace transform of $f_X(x)$ evaluated at $-t$.

$$\begin{align}
M_X(t) &= \mathcal{L}\{f_X(x)\}(-t) = \frac{1}{(1-3t)^2} \\
&\implies \mathcal{L}\{f_X(x)\}(t) = \frac{1}{(1+3t)^2} \\
&\implies f_X(x) = \mathcal{L}^{-1} \bigg\{\frac{1}{(1+3t)^2}\bigg\}
\end{align}$$

Which we can easily compute

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}^{-1} \bigg\{ \frac{1}{(1+3t)^2} \bigg\} &= \frac{1}{9} \mathcal{L}^{-1} \bigg\{ \frac{1}{(t + \frac{1}{3})^2} \bigg\} \\
&= \frac{1}{9} e^{-x/3} \mathcal{L}^{-1} \bigg\{ \frac{1}{t^2} \bigg\} \\
&= \frac{1}{9} e^{-x/3} x
\end{align}$$

Thus the probability density function $f_X(x)$ associated with the moment-generating function $M_X(t)$ assuming only positive values for $x$ is

$$f_X(x) = \frac{1}{9} x e^{-x/3}$$

Which turns out to be a Gamma distribution with $\theta = 3$ and $k = 2$ as [@Amir](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1231520/amir) mentioned.